# How to configure Solr to do partial word matching

Tags: solr, lucene, sunspot

Given the following set of values how do I configure the field to return values that are partial word matches but that also match the entire search term?

Values:

```
Texas State University
Stanford University
St. Johns College
```

### Desired results examples:

Search Term: `sta`

Desired Results:

```
Texas State University
Stanford University
```

Search Term: `stan`

Desired Results:

```
Stanford University
```

Search Term: `st un`

Desired Results:

```
Texas State University
Stanford University
```

### This is what I've tried so far:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I think my problem is with the `EdgeNGramFilterFactory`. As shown above, the second search for `stan` returns all three of the values shown instead of only `Stanford`. But, without the `EdgeNGramFilterFactory`, partial words don't match at all.

**What is the correct configuration for a Solr field to return values that are partial word matches but that also match the entire search term?**

Comment: If you are building a search with automatic suggestions you might want to take a look at the Suggest Search Component: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/suggester.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I figured it out. **I definitely welcome other answers and additional corrections though.**

The solution appears to be to only use the `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` when indexing, not when querying. This makes sense when you think about it. I want n-grams when indexing but only want to match the actual search term when querying.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar kind of requirment and tried this ... created different field Type...

```
<fieldType name="text_reference" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/> 
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

I another another requirement...
The below blog will explain it in detail

https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=8592878860404675342#editor/target=post;postID=6309840933546641223;onPublishedMenu=allposts;onClosedMenu=allposts;postNum=33;src=postname

Answer (score 1):

You can use

N-Gram Filter

Generates n-gram tokens of sizes in the given range. Note that tokens are ordered by position and then by gramsize.

Factory class:solr.NGramFilterFactory

Arguments:

minGramSize: (integer, default 1) The minimum gram size.
maxGramSize: (integer, default 2) The maximum gram size.

Example:

```
<analyzer>  
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

In: "four score"

Out: "f", "o", "u", "r", "fo", "ou", "ur", "s", "c", "o", "r", "e", "sc", "co", "or", "re"

http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-5.3.pdf#page=112&zoom=auto,-187,475